# i need a good website to learn c++

Tags: c++

i want to learn C++; and i already have a compiler.

i already know a few programming languages including:

- BASIC (yes, the dos version)
- visualBasic (using VisualBasic Express
  2006 or 8 i'm not quite sure)
- Java
- PHP
- HTML (if we count that)

so it doesn't need to be for absolute beginners; although if you find one post it too.

Comment: You're probably going to want to pick up a book on object oriented design since few those languages are "known" for having a very robust Object Oriented Programming feature set. If you're really as comfortable with Java as you claim, C++ In a Nutshell from O'Reilly should be enough, since Java is very similar and has a solid OOP background (if you're using it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/) is a great website with tons of documentation for experts and beginners.

Tutorials for beginners:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

An additional website I heartily reccomend once you have a little more expertise is the [C++ FAQ Lite.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/)

Answer (score 6):

The text of a good book is online here: [Thinking in C++](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html)

Comment: Later on, I would recommend the second part too. (Which is also online in the same web)

Comment: +1 for this suggestion, a truly excellent book.

Comment: I am not downvoting or anything, but IMHO that book is not a very good introduction to C++, although can be useful as a reference

Comment: Well I found it a good introduction, given that I knew other languages which is the OP's situation. It would not be the place to start for a beginner.

Answer (score 3):

G'day,

I know it isn't a website but I'd highly recommend working through the excellent book Accelerated C++ ([sanitised Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020170353X)) by Andy Koenig and Barbara Moo.

It'll start you off properly by approaching C++ as it's own language rather than C with OO bits "bolted on". And you get to work with STL right from the start.

Highly recommended.

HTH

cheers,

Answer (score 2):

It's not a tutorial per-se but the [C++ FAQ LITE](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) is an invaluable resource IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to highlight a website for C++ programming.

[Learn C++ Online](http://www.learncpponline.com) - www.learncpponline.com

The above website is still not completely updated I think. But this website helped me a lot in my studies. Hope it will be helpful for others as well

Answer (score 0):

Aprt from the useful links given by [@Doug T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960218/i-need-a-good-website-to-learn-c/960221#960221). You can have a look at the advanced puzzles of c++ @ http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/ ( of course after the basics)

Comment: @aJ. to learn c++?!?!?! that's not a good source to learn. to develop your c++ knowledge further definitely! but to learn c++!?!?! whoa! (-:

Comment: Thats why I told after the basics. I learnt many things from there and I believe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I second Rob Wells; "Accelerated C++" is an excellent book. It would be hard to do better.

I would like to add that pointers can be especially daunting coming from your background. One of the best explanations I have come across is here at the [Stanford CS web site](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/). They have several pdfs and even an animated video on the subject.